# vclactnband250.bpl is missing on non-delphi machine / runtime packages is false

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo

If I run a project depending on my design time package on another computer I suddenly get:

> The program can't start because vclactnband250.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

It used to work fine, I possibly changed some setting and sometime later, while copying to another PC, I noticed the executable being 10MB smaller and giving the error.

"Link with runtime packages" is false as I don't want to do that. 
If set to true, the file is yet another 10MB smaller.
Value from configs fields is cleared.
"clean", "build", same problem.

EDIT: using a runtime package as I should have done in the first place, I get:

> The program can't start because vclx250.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Comment: Designtime packages cannot be used outside the IDE (which is pretty clear by the use of *designtime* in the name). If the other machine is *non-delphi*, it clearly doesn't have the IDE in order to use that designtime package.

Comment: @KenWhite: sounds logical, but I've "always" done it this way, and only now doesn't work anymore. changing to "design and runtime" doesn't help. running outside the IDE is still ok.

Comment: No, it has not. Designtime package use outside the IDE was terminated in Delphi 2006, and has not been possible since then. Changing to *designtime and runtime* clearly won't work if you have a package that uses the IDE's designtime functionality. (Search your code for anything starting with *Design*. If it's there, the IDE is required in order for the packages to be available, and the designtime packages are not redistributable under the licensing terms.

Comment: while it did work until some days ago, I realise now it was wrong <g>. perhaps because the package was created < 2006...

Comment: I apparently was quite ignorant about this design/runtime thing... I basically used designtime because I also needed component registration and it 'just worked'...

Comment: @KenWhite OK, solved: I recreated the project; it must have had traces of my package misdemeanor...  thank you - not sure how to leave this question as your comment definitely put me on the right track